# Use rems in Facebook Page Plugin

Tags: facebook, responsive-design, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to set up Page Plugin on my website to display nicely on screens with a variety of resolutions and pixel densities. In order to truly achieve that, I'd have to have to possibility to use rems in `data-width` attribute. Unfortunately, when I enter a `rem` value, the `data-width` attribute is ignored. 
Is there a way to make the plugin behave nicely with rems?

Comment: No, there is not; as the documentation clearly states, it accepts a numeric value interpreted as pixels only.

Answer (score 1):

To make the Facebook Page Plugin responsive on initial page load, instead of using rems, you'll want to remove the data-width attribute and instead add

`data-adapt-container-width="true"`

This will make the Facebook Page Plugin responsive, but only on the initial page render, with a minimum width of 180px.

I'm still trying to figure out how to make it truly dynamically responsive, in spite of Facebook's caveat (I'll post an update if I ever find the answer).

> **No Dynamic Resizing**
>
> The Page plugin works with responsive, fluid and static layouts. You
>   can use media queries or other methods to set the `width` of the parent
>   element, yet:
>
> The plugin will determine its `width` on page load.
>   It will not react changes to the [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) after page load.
>   If you want to adjust the
>   plugin's `width` on window resize, you manually need to rerender the
>   plugin.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

You could make it dynamically responsive by reinitializing the widget on browser resize, but by doing that you run the risk of eating up memory very quickly.

There is some other stuff you can try here as well
[Responsive width Facebook Page Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin)