# Resizing facebook page plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, plugins

I am making a website right now for a client and I am connected his facebook page to the website using the page plugin from the facebook developers site. The only problem I am finding for it is that i need it's width to be in percentage so it would re-scale with the window. Anyone know how I can do this ?

Comment: what have you got so far? what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: "<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/santaluciafalconsfc/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="350" data-height="505" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/santaluciafalconsfc/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/santaluciafalconsfc/">SANTA LUCIA Falcons FC</a></blockquote></div>".                           that is the code that is generated by their own generator, i tried changing 'data-width' but it corrupts the code when I try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive width Facebook Page Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin)

Comment: I suggest taking a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin) :)