# Resizing facebook page plugin on XAMPP

Tags: jquery, html, xampp

I found the code below on a stack overflow page ([Responsive width Facebook Page Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin)). it works fine when I try it on live preview in brackets but it doesn't resize when i try it on XAMPP.Anyone know what the problem might be ?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=443271375714375";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).bind("load resize", function(){  
  setTimeout(function() {
  var container_width = $('#container').width();    
    $('#container').html('<div class="fb-page" ' + 
    'data-href="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat"' +
    ' data-width="' + container_width + '" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat">Auto*Mat</a></blockquote></div></div>');
    FB.XFBML.parse( );    
  }, 100);  
}); 
});

</script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%;">  
<div class="fb-page" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/IniciativaAutoMat">Auto*Mat</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Does the console return any errors? Is your jQuery loaded?