# Facebook page embed iframe doesn't fill container width

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I added an iframe of wikipedia to demonstrate the problem I have.
The Wiki iframe is displayed correctly like it suppose to, but the facebook iframe isn't.

[image]
[image]

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="iframe-fb-container mt-4">
      <iframe class="iframe-fb" width="450" height="700" style="border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/&tabs=timeline%2Cevents%2Cmessages&width=450px&height=700px&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=2235597906716847"></iframe>
      <iframe class="iframe-fb" width="450" height="700" style="border:1px solid black;overflow:hidden" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"></iframe>
   </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.iframe-fb-container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }

 .iframe-fb {
    width: 100%;
    }
```

As you can see I am asking facebook an iframe with width of **450px** and in the images attached the width of the emulator is **375px**, but still the fb iframe doesn't fill it container like the wikipedia iframe does.

How can I make fb iframe to fill it container?

Answer (score 5):

You can't make it 100% in a normal way.

This is your iframe src:

```
https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/&tabs=timeline%2Cevents%2Cmessages&width=450px&height=700px&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=2235597906716847"></iframe>
```

Note that there is parameter: `width=450px`.

It set the width of the iframe content to be 450px.

According to [Facebook Plugin documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/):

`The pixel width of the plugin. Min. is 180 & Max. is 500`.

So the maximum width Facebook can get is 500.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook states on the [Page Plugin site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#adaptive-width)

> The plugin will by default adapt to the width of its parent container on page load (min. 180px / max. 500px), useful for changing layout

and

> **No Dynamic Resizing**
>   The Page plugin works with responsive, fluid and static layouts. You can use media queries or other methods to set the width of the parent element, yet:
>   The plugin will determine its width on page load
>   It will not react changes to the box model after page load.
>   If you want to adjust the plugin's width on window resize, you manually need to rerender the plugin.

So I would think your best option would be to fill the width of the parent as much as possible (up to the 500px limit), and then centre it in the parent.
If you try over riding the CSS set by facebook, it starts to display incorrectly, such as the posts not filling the timeline.

Comment: As you can see in the attached images the width is  375px and I am asking fb 450px and don't get, the resize issue is well known.

Answer (score 2):

What about a jQuery solution?

```
jQuery(window).on("load resize", function () {
  jQuery('iframe[src*="facebook.com"]').each(function () {
    /* get width of parent element */
    var width = Math.round(jQuery(this).parent().width());
    if (width > 500) {
      width = 500;
    } else if (width < 180) {
      width = 180;
    }

    /* replace width value in iframe src */
    var src = new URL(jQuery(this).attr("src"));
    src.searchParams.set("width", width);

    /* append new width */
    jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
    jQuery(this).attr("width", width);
  });
});
```

This script gets the width of the parent element and adjusts the iframe accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's **Page Plugin** it's not working as a responsive container, you have to add width from **minimum 180px** to **maximum 500px** as per the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/).

[image]

You can also look at some other answers, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

[Responsive width Facebook Page Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin)

Comment: I requested `width=450`.

Answer (score 1):

After asking in the [facebook bug platform](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2203165469736837/) I got this answer from them which helped to solve this issue once and for all:

> As already answered by other people in stackoverflow, according to the
>   documentation,
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/, you can
>   specify the width for the plugin, however, **"100%" is not something
>   supported.**

Quotes from facebook documantion are not helping unless you refernce them against an error in the code, the documentation says as follows:

> The pixel width of the plugin. Min. is 180 & Max. is 500

It's not saying anything about not supporting 100% width of the parent container!
The only answer that was close to figure it out was Alon's and that's why he got the bounty.

So eventually this is the code I ended up with:

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="iframe-fb-container">
   <iframe class="iframe-fb border" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FGringo.co.il%2F&tabs=timeline&width=400&height=700&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=2235597906716847"></iframe>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.iframe-fb-container {
    text-align: center;
    width:400px;
    height:700px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.iframe-fb {
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope this answer will help someone in the future :)

Comment: but this one doesn't solve the responsive case.

Comment: @gumuruh there is no way to solve this, Facebook returns a maximum width of the Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Because **_2p3a** and **uiScaledImageContainer _2zfr** are taking width: 450px; that's why facebook iframe not showing correctly.

Comment: this is correct, i dont think it can be done due to fixed width div _2p3a  inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can always zoom iframe with scale:

```
iframe {
    transform: scale(1.3)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Please give the iframe width of 100%. :)

```
iframe{
  width: 100% !important  //important if not working without it..
}
```

Comment: will not work, as there are elements inside the iframe with fixed width that cannot be changed