# facebook feed not loading after jquery minified version update

Tags: jquery, firefox, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, mozilla

I have an artist page on my website and I am fetching particular artist feed from facebook widget. But I have recently updated jQuery minified version to the latest and it stopped working. This problem is occurring on Firefox Mozilla.

My html

```html
<div class="facebookContent" data-lazy-widget="facebook_1" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    <div id="facebook_1"></div>
</div>
```

My jquery version

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('jquery-3.6.0.min.js?v=' . VERSION); ?>" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script type='application/javascript' src="<?php echo base_url('jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js?v=' . VERSION); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js?v=' . VERSION); ?>" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

My feed code

```
function facefeeddata(){
    $('.facebookContent').html("");
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var facebookfeed = $("#facebookfeed").text(); 
        var facebookartist = $("#facebookartist").text();
        var container_width = $('.facebookContent').width();    
        var container_height = $('.facebookContent').height(); 
        $('.facebookContent').html('<div class="fb-page" ' + 'data-href="'+facebookfeed+'"' +' data-width="' + container_width + '" data-height="' + container_height + '" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="'+facebookfeed+'"><a href="'+facebookfeed+'">'+facebookartist+'</a></blockquote></div></div>');
        FB.XFBML.parse( );
    }, 1000); 
}
```

but when loading it gives me this error

> ErrorUtils caught an error:
>
> Minified invariant #11797;  Params: 113 [Caught in: Module
> "VisibilityListener"]
>
> Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see
> https://fburl.com/debugjs.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on all browsers

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm using jquery-3.5.1.min.js

Comment: Few have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429296/responsive-width-facebook-page-plugin/31971705 and they said that it works.

Comment: Ensure that there are no conflicts with other JavaScript libraries or frameworks. If another library is using the $ symbol, it can conflict with jQuery. Consider using jQuery's `noConflict()` method to avoid conflicts.